# Tensorflow Mobile- Creating a Conditional Statement based on the output

Tags: java, arrays, tensorflow

I am a novice at programming. I have setup Tensorflow mobile (I know tensor flow lite exists, but I am on windows, so I can't convert the .pb file to .lite)successfully on my pc, including a custom image recognition file. However, I would like to create a conditional statement based on the outputs of the Tensorflow prediction. E.g.- if the name of the highest predicted object is "Android" then print out an additional statement. I believe this is possible through the id class, which is the name of the output of the prediction, but am not quite sure what to do. Would you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) work? You can add a `tf.Print` operation to one branch, for example.

Comment: Just for reference, tensor flow for heroes provided an easy solution to my problem